# Direct3D11 shaders compile flags problems

Tags: c++, visual-studio, shader, directx-11

I am reading a book from Frank Luna 3D Game Programming with DirectX 11.

I was using **D3DX11CompileFromFileW()** function to compile shaders with flag **(D3D10_SHADER_DEBUG | D3D10_SHADER_SKIP_OPTIMIZATION)** and it was working ,but in new projects and some more advanced programs
although the project is compiled without errors it does not display objects.

After a lot working on it I realized if I use flag **(D3D10_SHADER_DEBUG)** or just **(D3D10_SHADER_SKIP_OPTIMIZATION)** it works properly but does not work when I OR them together **(i.e D3D10_SHADER_DEBUG | D3D10_SHADER_SKIP_OPTIMIZATION )**

I also tried fxc compiler and I ran into the same problem.
Is there any solution to use the flags together or maybe I can use only one of them (I have use them together in many projects but not recently. The book also use them together).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you should try is to use the [D3DCompiler API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3dcompiler/) directly rather than using the deprecated D3DX11 'wrapper' for it. Currently you are using the "#43" June 2010 release of the HLSL compiler, and there's been many bug-fixes since. The Windows 10 SDK provides the "#47" version of the HLSL compiler.

Note that with VS 2012 or later, you need to use some special setup to make sure your include/lib paths are correct for mixing the legacy DirectX SDK with the modern Windows 10 SDK which has many newer, overlapped headers. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-).

See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/hlsl-fxc-and-d3dcompile/) for more about the D3DCompile API.

> Frank's book is excellent, but it was published *before* the DirectX SDK was deprecated. See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/book-recommendations/) for relevant notes.